# How to add mean and sd lines with fill in a Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, standard-error

I've ran some MonteCarlo simulations on a pension scheme problem. I get all the simulation to appear in a ggplot but I'd like to have show also the mean and sd, having the gap between the sd's filled, just for aesthetics.

I've tried to get the means and sds on other datasets and/or use functions like stat_summary, geom_ribbon, and just doesnt work.

```
# Parameters
N     <- 22 # Number of Years Simulations
M     <- 100  # Number of Monte Carlo Simulations   
mu    <- 0.0588
sigma <- 0.115
year <- 2019:(N+2019)
price_init <-  6387786 
 #initial price
premium_payout <- c(2944227,    3417635,    3285270,    2799238,    2718016,    2579202,    2674255,    2990758,    3167386,    2773270,    2478602,    2569300,    2611695,    1933911,    1831078,    1459534,    1626927,    1728564,    1268749,    1383170,    1183889,    1095443,    1027536,    893171, 736958, 376525, 327245, 413949, 413974, 214892, 283205, 0,0,0,0,0)
pension_disimbursement<-c(-37190,   -1873850,   -4252838,   -1289580,   -2259324,   -2306284,   -992270,    -1066318,   -4424768,   -3365870,   -2119356,   -2469627,   -6943775,   -807525,    -4210481,   -1569241,   -372050,    -4909025,   -762436,    -1992166,   -2223456,   -1051695,   -2978799,   -2083058,   -2755359,   -1499381,   -0, -0, -2216731,   -0, -2335107,-0,-0,-0,-0,-0)




# Simulate prices
set.seed(123)
monte_carlo_mat <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = M)
for (j in 1:M) {
  monte_carlo_mat[[1, j]] <- price_init
  for(i in 2:N) {
    monte_carlo_mat[[i, j]] <- (monte_carlo_mat[[i - 1, j]] + pension_disimbursement[i - 1])   * (1 + rnorm(1, mu, sigma)) + premium_payout[i-1]
  }
}
# Format and organize data frame
price_sim <- cbind(year, monte_carlo_mat) %>%
  as_tibble() 
nm <- str_c("Sim.", seq(1, M))
nm <- c("Year", nm)
names(price_sim) <- nm
price_sim <- price_sim %>%
  gather(key = "Simulation", value = "Balance", -(Year))




#plot with all lines of simulations
price_sim %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Balance, Group = Simulation))  + #define axis by simulation group and color them
  geom_line(alpha = 0.1) + #transparency of the line
  ggtitle(str_c("HR Yara:", M, 
                " Monte Carlo Simulations for Balance Over ", N, 
                " Years"))+ #title definition
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60 ,hjust = 1))+ #x axis in 60 degrees agle and out of the graph 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar)+ #money sign
  labs(y = "Balance (EUR)")+ # y axis label
  theme(legend.position = "none", #no legend for the colors of each simulation
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "darkblue", size = 12, face = "bold.italic"),
        axis.title = element_text(color = "darkblue", size = 10, face= "italic"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color="black", size = 8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black", size = 7),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray"), 
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "transparent")) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(2019, 2040), ylim = c(0, 60000000))
```

I just want the same graph with the mean and sd's having them filled, I've burned my head already, dont know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify it in aesthetic specifications with fill option like this:

```
ggplot(aes(fill = my_means))
```

and

```
ggplot(aes(fill = my_sds))
```